# IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 Scala plugin isn't working with new projects

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I just formatted my computer and installed the new macOS Big Sur. I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 with the Scala plugin version 2020.3.17. I'm running GraalVM 20.3, Scala 2.13.4 and sbt 1.4.4 outside IntelliJ with no issues so far.

IntelliJ loads my projects just fine and everything works perfectly. The problem is when I try to create a new Scala/sbt project. IntelliJ isn't creating the ***build*** module as expected and, because of that, IntelliJ doesn't recognize any source code at all.

All installs were clean, I didn't recovered from any backup, just installed as it was a new computer. I also own a valid IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate license. I tried uninstalling everything, but with no success. There's no way I can make it work.

The steps to reproduce my issue:

*Open IntelliJ IDEA -> New project -> Select Scala on the left panel -> Select sbt on the right panel -> All defaults on next screen -> Wait for IntelliJ to index everything and creates the modules.*

That's it. After finishing indexing, no build module is created. If I open my `build.sbt` file, all it shows is it can't find any symbol and it doesn't highlight the `src/main/scala` as source code folder. Actually, it doesn't highlight any folder at all.

Anyone out there with the same issue and/or solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is gone with latest updates from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same problem as you. I rebuilt the project step by step by creating a new one starting from the sbt dependencies and plugins. Basically I solved it by setting the sbt version to sbt.version = 0.13.18 inside the project / build.properties folder. By inserting scala-sdk-2.12.12 as global libraries in the project structure and Java 12 as SDK